# WSO2 ESB on Carbon 4.2 - Did not find the desired phase 'Transport' while deploying handler 'POXSecurityHandler'

Tags: esb, wso2

I'm new to WSO2 ESB and would like to try it out for some external integrations.
I've installed the WSO2 Carbon 4.2 server and installed the ESB feature 4.8.1.
After a restart, I'm getting some errors as below.
Any tips or suggestions would be gratefully accepted.

Thanks.

```
[2014-03-06 10:01:08,521]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2014-03-06 10:01:08,525] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Couldn't initialize the ESB...
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The synapse.xml location ././
        ./repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs
    /default doesn't exist
    at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.handleFatal(SynapseControllerFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.validatePath(SynapseControllerFactory.java:113)
    at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.validate(SynapseControllerFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.createSynapseController(SynapseControllerFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:423)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
...
...
...
[2014-03-06 10:01:08,531]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.rule.kernel.internal.ds.RuleEngineConfigDS} -  Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[2014-03-06 10:01:08,553] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.security.internal.SecurityMgtServiceComponent} -  Failed to activate SecurityMgtServiceComponent
org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseException: Did not find the desired phase 'Transport' while deploying handler 'POXSecurityHandler'.
    at org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseHolder.addHandler(PhaseHolder.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseResolver.engageModuleToFlow(PhaseResolver.java:68)
    at org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseResolver.engageModuleToOperation(PhaseResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseResolver.engageModuleToOperation(PhaseResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation.onEngage(AxisOperation.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.engageModule(AxisDescription.java:478)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.onEngage(AxisService.java:827)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.engageModule(AxisDescription.java:478)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisServiceGroup.onEngage(AxisServiceGroup.java:134)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the second exception -

```
"org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseException: Did not find the desired phase 'Transport' while deploying handler 'POXSecurityHandler'."
```

This is because the 'Transport' phase is missing in the 'OutFaultFlow' of the axis2.xml. This is a recent addition hence it's missing when you did the feature installation. To fix this issue,

- Search for the OutFaultFlow in the repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
- In there, just after the 'Security' phase add the new entry 'Transport' as follows

.

```
<phase name="Transport"/>
```

- Restart the server

Answer (score 1):

Even though, WSO2 Carbon supports any feature installation via P2, there are some configurations not coming via the feature installation.

If you compare the [ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) product with the customized product you have, you will see there are many differences in the config files. Please take a look at [how ESB distribution is created](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/distribution).

There are two errors in your case.

1. > org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The synapse.xml location ././
   >       ./repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default doesn't exist

This means that it cannot find the synapse.xml in `/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default`. This is missing as it comes via the product distribution.

1. > org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseException: Did not find the desired phase 'Transport' while deploying handler 'POXSecurityHandler'.

This probably means that Axis2 to cannot find the "Transport" phase required by a security component. The "Transport" phase is available in [ESB 4.8.1 axis2.xml](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/distribution/src/main/conf/axis2.xml).

In summary, my *personal opinion* is that you should not try to install ESB features on WSO2 Carbon. If I need a product with multiple features, I would start with ESB first.

While feature installation provides you more flexibility, it will not always work smoothly. However there are many useful cases that we can install features on top of WSO2 Products.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to get the WSO2 ESB distribution downloaded and running.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I should first use the WSO2 ESB distribution and then add features to that one instead? I am also interested in other components like for e.g. API Manager and Data Services Server and will try that out soon.

Comment: Yes. I have used DSS features on ESB successfully and it's a common use case. However I'm not sure about API Manager.

Answer (score 0):

For the first exception see the bug resolution comment at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-776

I also copied in the synapsis.xml file from the ESB distribution given by Isuru

Comment: Link only answers are not as useful as answers than include the link, but then go on to explain the relevant parts of the linked content so that if the link ever goes down the answer is still viable.

Comment: Ok - see [https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/distribution/](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/distribution/) for the synapsis.xml file in the current release of WSO2 Carbon